# How do I apply a patch visually from a foreign repo into mine?

Tags: git, patch

A colleague sent me a patch from his git repo. Since it's not a clone, his `index` entry contains hashes that are not known in my repo. Sample:

```
index 20589f5..bbdd152 100644
```

`20589f5` exists in his repo but not in mine.

When I try to apply the patch using TortoiseMerge, I get the message

```
fatal: not a valid object name
```

**How could I trick TortoiseMerge into accepting the patch?**

---

Edit: It doesn't have to be TortioseMerge. Any other tool that lets me apply my patch visually (and runs on Windows, preferably free) is good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is from a colleague, the best answer is to simply have him provide the missing data, either via a patch series or by letting you fetch from his repository. If you can get this data, any other route is just a waste of time.

Otherwise, you have have a patch that does not apply cleanly to your current work tree, and you don't have enough information to perform a 3-way merge.

Now, if you want to try applying the patch anyway, I suggest using `git am` (or `git apply`, if he provided a diff instead of a patch -- which is bad practice) to attempt to apply the patch. You can use the `--reject` option to force it to be applied as much as possible. Git will create `.rej' files for diff hunks that did not apply cleanly to your current tree. You can then go and attempt to  apply these manually.

Another option is to simply manually apply the entire patch via your editor.

There is no need to use `patch` as suggested elsewhere. `git apply` will always be preferable.

Now, you want to do this visually, and the best suggestion I can offer is the pseudo-visual `--interactive` mode of `git apply`. This will allow you to apply the patch hunk by hunk.

You can't do this with Tortoisemerge because Tortoisemerge [is expecting](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html) two or three complete files in order to perform the merge. Since your index values don't correspond to known blobs in your repository, you can't provide the complete base file revision to Tortoisemerge.

Comment: I'll give the bounty to you for the explanation why it cannot be done with TortoiseMerge.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know know if I provided enough info. I know this wasn't the answer you wanted :)

Answer (score 3):

Git patches are really just unified diffs in mbox format. If you don't care about the Git meta-data or merge history, you can feed the patch files directly to the *patch* command on the command line. For example:

```
cd /path/to/project
patch < 0001-foo.patch
```

This certainly works, but using git-bundle(1) to transfer a complete branch might be a better way to go if maintaining history is important to you.

Comment: while this answer is working (+1 for that), I explicitly want to know how I could apply the patch **visually**, therefore with TortoiseMerge.

Answer (score 1):

If your start up TortoiseMerge manually without any arguments, a dialog will prompt you to choose between "Merging" and "Apply unified diff". Choose the latter and select the patch as "Diff file" and your Git working tree as "Directory". After pressing "OK" a window listing all files the patch modified appears. Then either click on "Patch all items" or select a file and click on "Patch select item". This will then visually apply the patch within TortoiseMerge.

Comment: unfortunately not: still getting `fatal: Not a valid object name`